transform.decorator.ts:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')
i am trying to convert json response to class so i can  use it with react hoook form.
This is my class:
export class MyClass {
...
  @Transform(({ value }) => {
    if (value === null) return "";
    else return value;
  })
  myKey: string | number;
...
}

This is my vite config:
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      babel: {
        plugins: [
          ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { version: "2023-11" }],
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
});

But when i call plainToInstance(MyClass, data)
I get this error:
transform.decorator.ts:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor')

This is the code where transform has problem (when i click on line 15):
export function Transform(
  transformFn: (params: TransformFnParams) => any,
  options: TransformOptions = {}
): PropertyDecorator {
  return function (target: any, propertyName: string | Symbol): void {
    defaultMetadataStorage.addTransformMetadata({
      target: target.constructor,   <---------------
      propertyName: propertyName as string,
      transformFn,
      options,
    });
  };
}

What is the problem here? Trying to fix it for the last 3 hours.
